# How do I convert cities surrounded by sea to my religion?

Tags: civilization-5-gods-and-kings

One can build a city on a single tile of land surrounded by water on all sides. How can I convert such a city to my religion, if I can't have a missionary (on land) next to them ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A missionary doesn't have to be on land to convert a city; it just needs to be in an adjacent tile. So you can use a missionary from a coastal tile next to the city to convert citizens in it.

Comment: gosh, I was so convinced it wasn't possible I didn't even try !

Comment: I just did it twice - and it seemed to have no effect - yet one of my missionaries from land did work imbetween the 2 tries